# Antonym for Perception?

Tags: antonyms

What would be the closest thing to an antonym for the word "Perception" (noun), which means "that which is received through the senses"? It seems like there are no definite antonyms for this word.

Comment: This is unclear. Do you want things that are _not_ received through the senses? Or things that are doing the receiving? Or do you want a counterpart to perception, things that are processed mentally but are not perceptions? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### <del>Overlook</del> Oversight.

Because, to overlook something is to not perceive it.

Comment: I think this is as close as I can get, but is there any words you know of related to this but are a noun? Like what you would get from overlooking something possibly?

Comment: a neglection maybe?

Comment: You can use overlooking as a noun.  The **overlooking** of the answer caused me to fail.

Comment: Thank you! This was close to what I was trying to think of!

Comment: The **ceive** part is latin for *to give*, so the only opposite really is... *to not give*, to keep, I suppose.

Comment: "Oversight" seems to be a good noun for overlooking.

Comment: I concur with that oversight of mine!

Comment: I'm going to troll my 2cts of opinion again - Most questions asking for antonyms are illogical because they neglect (or refuse) to constrain their subjective romantic case down to a less romantic binary state. Without a binary state there can be no antonymic situation. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195376/whats-the-antonym-of-stage-name/195389#195389

Comment: The only logical antonym to an unconstrained & non-binary entity A = not A. Therefore, the only logical antonym to *perception* = *not perception*.

Answer (score 3):

That which is perceived by extrasensory means might be *deduction* or *intuition*.

That which is not perceived at all might be *ignorance* or the like.

What part of "Perception"'s meaning do you want to negate?

Comment: Well by perception I basically mean a sense or feeling. So I guess I would be trying to find a word that almost means not to feel or possibly to ignore a feeling or sense.

Answer (score 2):

> a word that almost means not to feel or possibly to ignore a feeling
>   or sense.

**Insensitivity**

Definition of the adjective insensitive:

1. lacking some element or characteristic; defective, deficient in
   taste.
2. insufficient; inadequate, deficient knowledge.

Comment: Thank you, I would upvote the answer but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 1):

What about **"numbness"**?

> - numbness (noun) "the state of lacking in emotion or feeling. [D.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/numbness)

Comment: Thank you, I would upvote the answer but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: Still don't have 15 rep, sorry =(.

Answer (score 1):

[Oblivion](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/oblivion) comes close: #2: "the state of being [oblivious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/oblivious)," which in turn = "unmindful; unconscious; unaware."

(Dictionary Reference)

"While in that state of oblivion he had no perception of his surroundings."

Answer (score 1):

Obliviousness

Ability to block things out

Detachment

Disconnectedness

Self-centeredness

Inability to listen

Self-absorption

Spaciness

Dreaminess

Inattentiveness

Tendency to be somewhere else (OR in his own world) even while he's sitting across the table from you

Answer (score 0):

The idea of reality can be the opposite of that of perception. Perception is how one view and see something. In contrast, reality has a definite meaning.